# Toggle Class of Div with <img> click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there I'm trying to toggle the class of a div with the clicking of a button but seems to be not working, any suggestion?

HTML

```
<img id="downarrow" src="images/downarrow.svg"/>

<div class="responsive-subscribe">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.responsive-subscribe {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: ;
bottom: 10px;
display: none;
}

.open {
display: block;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $downarrow = $('#downarrow');

    $downarrow.click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.responsive-subscribe').toggleClass('.open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.responsive-subscribe').toggleClass('.open');` Should be like `$('.responsive-subscribe').toggleClass('open');`

remove `.` from `.toggleClass('.open');`

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkL4hb8w/)**

Comment: thanks @ketan now I see, I don't have to put then the . for the classes in this case! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo, remove the '.' from the .toggleClass:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $downarrow = $('#downarrow');

    $downarrow.click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.responsive-subscribe').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/0wcn5L7h/1/